# Using an ODBC application with a JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, odbc, pyodbc, vertica

My company uses [Vertica](http://www.vertica.com/).  We have Python applications that connect to it with pyodbc.  I do most of my development on a Mac (Snow Leopard) and unfortunately Vertica has not released ODBC drivers for Mac.  They do have JDBC drivers though.  I don't think developing in Jython is a good compromise.  Is there any way to use JDBC drivers with an ODBC application?  Some kind of ODBC connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit: update for vertica 5/6 can be found here https://github.com/serbaut/psycopg2

Here is a patch to make psycopg2 2.2.1 work with vertica 4.0. No ODBC needed.

```
diff --git a/psycopg/connection_int.c b/psycopg/connection_int.c
index 902fdbb..b07eee8 100644
--- a/psycopg/connection_int.c
+++ b/psycopg/connection_int.c
@@ -280,6 +280,10 @@ conn_setup(connectionObject *self, PGconn *pgconn)
         pgres = psyco_exec_green(self, psyco_datestyle);
     }

+    if (self->server_version == 0 && self->protocol == 3) { /* vertica */
+      self->encoding = strdup("UTF8");
+      self->isolation_level = 0;
+    } else {
     if (pgres == NULL || PQresultStatus(pgres) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK ) {
         PyErr_SetString(OperationalError, "can't set datestyle to ISO");
         IFCLEARPGRES(pgres);
@@ -335,7 +339,7 @@ conn_setup(connectionObject *self, PGconn *pgconn)
         return -1;
     }
     self->isolation_level = conn_get_isolation_level(pgres);
-
+    }
     Py_UNBLOCK_THREADS;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&self->lock);
     Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS;
diff --git a/psycopg/typecast_builtins.c b/psycopg/typecast_builtins.c
index e8e5a1a..45b9dbc 100644
--- a/psycopg/typecast_builtins.c
+++ b/psycopg/typecast_builtins.c
@@ -1,15 +1,15 @@
 static long int typecast_NUMBER_types[] = {20, 23, 21, 701, 700, 1700, 0};
-static long int typecast_LONGINTEGER_types[] = {20, 0};
+static long int typecast_LONGINTEGER_types[] = {6, 20, 0};
 static long int typecast_INTEGER_types[] = {23, 21, 0};
-static long int typecast_FLOAT_types[] = {701, 700, 0};
-static long int typecast_DECIMAL_types[] = {1700, 0};
-static long int typecast_UNICODE_types[] = {19, 18, 25, 1042, 1043, 0};
+static long int typecast_FLOAT_types[] = {7, 701, 700, 0};
+static long int typecast_DECIMAL_types[] = {16, 1700, 0};
+static long int typecast_UNICODE_types[] = {8, 9, 19, 18, 25, 1042, 1043, 0};
 static long int typecast_STRING_types[] = {19, 18, 25, 1042, 1043, 0};
-static long int typecast_BOOLEAN_types[] = {16, 0};
-static long int typecast_DATETIME_types[] = {1114, 1184, 704, 1186, 0};
-static long int typecast_TIME_types[] = {1083, 1266, 0};
-static long int typecast_DATE_types[] = {1082, 0};
-static long int typecast_INTERVAL_types[] = {704, 1186, 0};
+static long int typecast_BOOLEAN_types[] = {5, 0};
+static long int typecast_DATETIME_types[] = {12, 13, 1114, 1184, 704, 1186, 0};
+static long int typecast_TIME_types[] = {11, 15, 1083, 1266, 0};
+static long int typecast_DATE_types[] = {10, 1082, 0};
+static long int typecast_INTERVAL_types[] = {14, 704, 1186, 0};
 static long int typecast_BINARY_types[] = {17, 0};
 static long int typecast_ROWID_types[] = {26, 0};
 static long int typecast_LONGINTEGERARRAY_types[] = {1016, 0};
```

Comment: I'm just going to assume this answers the question.  I'm not able to verify it though, as I haven't had a need for Vertica in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ODBC-over-JDBC bridges.  [OpenLink](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc/st/odbc-jdbc-bridge-st/), among others, provides one for Mac OS.

Comment: I haven't tried it.  However, the product includes basic support (http://support.openlinksw.com/supportweb/SupportServicesFAQ#SupportContractNeeded).

Comment: You mean I have to buy it before they'll explain how it works?  This site is so businessy.  I don't see developer documentation anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I found it.  http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/InstallODBCJDBCLiteOSX

Answer (score 0):

As of Vertica 6 there are native ODBC drivers for Mac OS X available from the https://my.vertica.com portal