# Python Vertica Insert

Tags: python, vertica

I've been trying to load data into a Vertica DB using Python.

```
def test():
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(db_connect_string)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        print 'Error %s' % e
        sys.exit(1)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO <table_name> (cusip, ticker) VALUES (%s, %s)"% (1234, "'tkr'"))
    connection.commit()
```

That returns without an error but subsequent SELECTS don't return anything. (NOTE: the SELECT code as been independently tested and works).

Comment: Works for me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695684/using-an-odbc-application-with-a-jdbc-driver/2916918#2916918 . With a vanilla psycopg2 you should get an exception on connect.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to your issue? i am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using psycopg2 which is targeted to postgres, maybe using pyodbc instead (suggested by the vertica doc) would solve your issue?

There is open source library we developed at $work to help using vertica with python and more specifically to insert data the proper Vertica way (single INSERTs are veeerryyy slow). Maybe it could help you: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvertica

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO <table_name> (cusip, ticker) VALUES (%s, %s)"% (1234, "'tkr'");commit;)
```

or 
change

```
connection.commit()
```

by

```
cursor.execute("commit")
```